# OOP - How to demand derived classes to set a value to base attribute?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, derived-class, base-class

The output of my program is a table in a file.

Some users like the output as Excel file, the others prefer CSV, and so on.
  I therefore have an abstarct class `Document` with 2 derived classes:
  `ExcelDocument` and `CsvDocument`.

The delimiter between the output results is different in each class:
In the CSV file the delimiter is `,` and in the Excel the delimiter is `/t`.

How can I force the derived classes to set value to the `delimiter` attribute of the abstract `Document` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an abstract property:

```
public abstract char Delimiter { get; }
```

Then in your derived class:

```
public override char Delimiter
{
    get { return '\t'; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. where should the derived class set its value?

Comment: I have updated with an example derived class implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing: why do you use the Getter instaed of Setter?

Comment: In this case the value you will be returning from each derived class is known at design time, so you can return the constant value from the Getter. There is no need for the property to have a Setter as you will never need to set the value during runtime.